# How to handle two buttons pressed event at the same time in android

Tags: android, android-asynctask, esp8266, nodemcu

I have developing an `android` app to rc car over wifi.I have used `esp8266 nodemcu` wifi module for this purpose. In my app. there are 4 buttons which are forward,reverse,right and left. I can connect this module over wifi and do some basic operations for ex. move forward, move reverse,turn right,turn left. Here are the codes that does this operations:

```
 @Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    String action;

    if (v.getId() == moveForward.getId())
        action = "/forward/";

    else if (v.getId() == moveReverse.getId())
        action = "/reverse/";

    else if (v.getId() == moveRigth.getId())
        action = "/right/";

    else
        action = "/left/";

    String serverAddress = ipAddress.getText().toString() + ":" + "80" + action;

    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        HttpRequestTask requestTask = new HttpRequestTask(serverAddress);
        requestTask.execute("1");

    } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        HttpRequestTask requestTask = new HttpRequestTask(serverAddress);
        requestTask.execute("0");
    }
    return false;
}

 private class HttpRequestTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    private String serverAdress;
    private String serverResponse = "";

    public HttpRequestTask(String serverAdress) {
        this.serverAdress = serverAdress;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        String val = params[0];
        String url = "http://" + serverAdress + val;
        Log.e("url", url);

        try {
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet();
            getRequest.setURI(new URI(url));
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(getRequest);

            InputStream inputStream = null;
            inputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader =
                    new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

            serverResponse = bufferedReader.readLine();
            inputStream.close();

        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            serverResponse = e.getMessage();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            serverResponse = e.getMessage();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            serverResponse = e.getMessage();
        }

        return serverResponse;
    }
```

When the user pressed forward also can be pressed right button or left button and the car goes forward and turn right or move reverse and turn left at the same time. But I couldn't a way how can I handle the two buttons pressed event at the same time in the code. Can you show me a way?

Comment: did your screen support multi touch ?

Comment: @OussemaAroua I don't know. If it is , how to handle it ?

Comment: just add android:splitMotionEvents="true" at your content layout

Comment: @OussemaAroua ok but any changes in the code ?

Comment: @OussemaAroua I have added  `android:splitMotionEvents="true"` this line. But it's not what I want. For ex when pressed forward button the car goes forward at the same time pressed right button the car turns right but it must goes forward and turns right. So this is the problem that I ask the above?

Comment: make them all if not if else

Comment: @OussemaAroua I am sorry, don't understand. Can you show me?

Comment: I'm not familiar with what your doing (rc car and all) but I get the code and the behavior you're aiming for. Is it possible if you pass two actions? Like for example `"/forward/right/` or something like that?

Comment: @McAwesomville Exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: I see. Then I guess it does have to do with your implementation. I haven't tried `splitMotionEvents="true"` before, but wouldn't concatenating the two actions (after making the `splitMotionEvents` thing work) be the solution? Since you are passing the action one by one. Unless your server side is handling the queue in a way that it would combine it.

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (v.getId() == moveForward.getId())
        action = "/forward/";

 if (v.getId() == moveReverse.getId())
        action = "/reverse/";

 if (v.getId() == moveRigth.getId())
        action = "/right/";

 if (v.getId() == moveLeft.getId())
        action = "/left/";
```

so you can handle all the motion, your old code will test for one condition only

Comment: I have tried it but nothing has changed. I can handle the request in server side like this code ex. `if (req.indexOf("/forward/0") != -1)
      forwardValue = 0;
  
  if (req.indexOf("/forward/1") != -1)
      forwardValue = 1;` This code only handle one parameters from the request. Do you think the problem is the server side ?

Comment: are sure your screen support multi touch ? log in the server the data received from the app

Comment: I have use Galaxy J5 I think it  supports multitouch. I couldn't solve the problem if a button pressed at the same time the other button pressed the second one overrides the first one.For ex. I pressed forward , the app requests the server `http://Ip:80/forward/1`  and then the server looks this request contains `forward/1` it gives 1 the pins and at the same time  I press right button , the app requests the server `http://Ip:80/right/1` and the server looks this request contains `right/1` it gives 1 the pins but at this time the app request the server like `http://Ip:80/forward/1/right/1` ?

Comment: http://Ip:80/forward/1/right/1 shows that the two touches is working, you have to handle this at server side

Comment: I will do it like that . But how to know the forward and right button pressed at the same time, how can I controll it in the app?

Comment: they are because the string is composed of two direction, the /forward/1/right/1 is stored at the string called "action"